# Named event/callback handler with inheritence in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm stuck right now an an issue with Typescript.

I have built a named callback Handler class that gets the allowed list of "events"/"handlernames" as a generic:

```
class NamedHandler<H extends { [key: string]: HandlerFunction }> {
...
```

Now I want to use this in other classes. This also works fine basically when it is a simple usecase on one class.

```
export class MyClass<H extends { [key: string]: HandlerFunction }> {
    protected commandHandler = new NamedHandler<H>();
    ... 
}

type SimpleHandlers = {
    handlerA: (param: number) => Promise<void>;
}

class SimpleClass<H extends { [key: string]: HandlerFunction }> extends MyClass<SimpleHandlers> {
```

But now I would like to extend from that class and also extend the allowed "handler names" and Here I do not come to any conclusion on how to do that (if it is even possible).

I put a full example in the [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAEghgOwCYBsICcBiBXBBjYASwHsEoBeKACgDo650BzAZwC4pEQBtAXQEoKAPigAFdMQC2hZhAA8nQQG4AsACg1eFHGbMoAOTgSISeMjTpZMKBAAewCMl0BvKFwDWEEO2bB0hBIw87KaoGDj4RKRQAL7CTmpQiVBgfgBucPZQABaIoejsLnAEJAjsHiDEAGawADTZuebB7p5VsDwxvBSuPCrqqkkcSCYNGLIA0tZ2Dki65a0wglRFkaVQY3U5ZhhNY-xQ8f0DScBZ0jSbeTRg2MxZVIXFpBsj6DF8vQPRaglJ2iD4kwgeGw9hC5nGk3sjigc2qCyWj1W6ygdBoDBY7BEDEMEHs6GYli4u0EAgORySlWIryoeFIPn2HER7Dgzy2r2iUFaJzOF3MpJ+5IGhGqSwo5EoyxK-MOgsFcAA7nBCMB6mzaPQmMx3gLZTEdZ8dV8+gN0BAJMRUhAwaMJrYoTMYS04YtJaR2MjedtYES9mTBdzmOcXl0A0G2TRKoQUHiqPdGStmay8uwsm8hPt9YLTcBsOgyHAoABCcXxkpQABk5eyRZLnvQH0F0W1Mr1qiNalsYCpKs02l0AFkQABhLQ6SyQ6bOVzlby+fyBYIvcKImJxHUpYj2AjGKC0iQSXLW16UBAQeX6HHDNmWRbNnVwIZDyQH5BHiF2yeOirOmnP3LupNGm9XZpVlUM9xfK9LgfKDzF-fdckAjBmwNY0klNc1LSfBDXxed8pmhWFYEWCD-zWJD8mA31M0ScC-1w8MMItK0XngyCKJQpIjXbVRQEgKAAGVCAkMA0CPXRKD9RJSOQABBdgqDAbEJHYBBsAkAAjZD0zESRpDkVJiEIJAlDUHjex0QThNEiARz7ccP2hFxmi8KAfD8AIglgJdcBXWIJ2hQc7LHISRLEl5mDXFt7B8KhQP9U5Axk2CMBoWwgRBFi1QAImS2TsrqABWTjyQAelKqA+PnNzsDALt0BVLIMGgOAUBQKBI1PGjKsSmhkqPNKbAy0FWOyyliAKqBiobRJuO+VRaQQelmGstAulPc9Qps4LmDi3oVrCiA0UfeiUvQKhctO-K6j+AFFOUgRyGERbmGINAaBQYhGHu9BDD4ZtyqgAAVKN2qa00ODaqBpA6-wIHmwHWteyrwGq5havqxrmpROgOGQSHkcYQhLV0RBrHQcRXm0SZIG3JA1AOmzjqQbDIKPC6NJQbANI0ybbrwaglN+iRHueuk3qOz7vqFv671UQGACEQSgBBiHPABJKB5WIbAUCQKAUEIDxKuIAL9cQTdwd3UdSfxpAMGJ6BKnECQoA07QWvxxUEBVYBTcc-WThatq1Z3Bw5wgQM1EV5WsjVnqYbwMmtKgbLfEQZhKgwU1A9NoPkgYcPrb7AB+ea+OgABRAj7bOiSrMO8SKygNQpN3U6FYUmWEBUlX1K09BRdEF39NkQzjNMtt5os3Rq-tYwdrN3QtrQHbZDn6ZjHEqKBhi4A4ozFsBkBgNod0HxQchz75WMbq6Jws7BuGrK8guvLJum+bZUBoHErcuPdb6xTq1a+O4-am1VueLSScbjQH8D1aAG0UaQDvr1fqLwn7AhGjlZKCsP4lSON1E+f9bg6z1m5YAcAQB43JpTVBZx0HhnSlgl+cExrEAmkVAhc0+gvRVAHHcJ4zxQA3sgBeNs9odhrsYZmrNDyjXfjdZg-wBY-T+umF6EsPpfTUSLZsAikCyNOuzS6D88FKJUYLB6GjxbvSlro-6vQDFGIfiY8afNlF3RliLGxS0tH2O8Y4+aQA)

if anyone sees a way to solve that or alternatives that would be cool.
Thank you

Comment: `class SimpleClass<H extends HandlerObj> extends MyClass<SimpleHandlers>` <-- The problem here is `SimpleHandlers` is named specifically - you need to pass `H` instead.

Comment: Your `removeHandler` seems to be implemented incorrectly

Comment: @Dai Thank you. If I change that (if I understand you correctly to)

```
class SimpleClass<H extends SimpleHandlers> extends MyClass<H> {
```

Then I get 

Argument of type '[5]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Parameters<H["commandA"]>'.(2345)

in the line with 

```
        this.commandHandler.executeHandler("commandA", 5);

```

And thank you for the removeHandler hint, yes ... 
I think it needs to be 

```
            return a !== action || h !== handler;
```
( but thats a side story) :-)

Comment: @IngoFischer That's a separate question entirely - I'm guessing you're new to Utility Types like `Parameters<T>`?

Comment: @Dai That's true - I just wonder why it works fine in some cases (see my comment to your answer) but not after your change

Answer (score 0):

- The (unwanted) errors happen in `class ExtendedClass extends SimpleClass<ExtendedHandlers>`.
- `SimpleClass<ExtendedHandlers>` is defined as:

  ```
  class SimpleClass<H extends HandlerObj> extends MyClass<SimpleHandlers> { ... }
  ```

  - ...which hardcodes the type `SimpleHandlers`, which lacks a member named `commandB`.
- The solution is to pass `SimpleClass<H>`'s `H` type-parameter into `MyClass<H>`:

  ```js
  class SimpleClass<H extends HandlerObj> extends MyClass<H>  { ... }
  ```
- ...[which works as-expected in TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAEghgOwCYBsICcBiBXBBjYASwHsEoBeKACgDo650BzAZwC4pEQBtAXQEoKAPigAFdMQC2hZhAA8nQQG4AsACg1oSLESoMAeQBGAKwpQA3lC4BrCCHbNg6QgkY928ZGiy4CJMgF8VdVU8FDhmZigAOTgJCCQPXXRZGCgIAA9gCGRIxK9DI2EzNShSqDAnADc4LKgACx0vdgs4X1J2GxBiADNYABp6xox3a1se2B4of15TXiCSsrgkBKHkgGk0zOykSM7xmEEqVqJ2qDWBhs9h2C41-nMFsrLgOukaS6SaMGxmOqoWtoIC6rKZ8IJPfxqR4cZggfCbCB4bBZPIYWQbDJZHJQPa9A5HQHsc5QOg0BgsdgiBixCBZdDMFK3HiCATFVRPJ7dYjoah4UgOcwcQkcYFXHn%20KDjF5vD5eVnQjllQi9I4UciUY5%20eXsxW60pwADucEIwEGYto9CYzDBCt1kJ1ivtEKhDqg6AgEmIlQgqPWmyxOxxYzxh01p2JsuuMCZ2r10uY7xBlHjibFNG6hBQdKo-yFJwQ7DgoqS7DqoKED1devdwGw6DIcCgAEJ1Xm-FAAGQd%20rN1uR9Dgu02132%201qDJgbmm0LhSIAWRAAGEwhEUv7trlVgUitCKsQsgR4lA%20RIJDpfaYEBADdEaSsxSlDsPoUskIvJGfkL70evsbjYIcJ6fkgRLFk0Nx3LGuopkB56rGSyy%20lQsHIGBGDDs6wRPO6nreu%20p5wQ%20GJbH%20wYAchH46KBZolhB9xsnGrwJih96fDhXo%20qsFEEahNFyoOpSji6mjQAAyoQEhgGgvqRJQDFlCxACC7BUGA1ISOwCDYBIBjoRWYiSNIciVMQhBIEoahjiEK6ROJkloMus5rpiG7aGK26-oGC6OauByVk8WQOFQUGKjBlFfvBGSIsinHmgAREpcUDAArBhuoAPTpVAmjOIwUDMNgYCTugpp1Bg0BwCgKBQBmV5qJloVMTQLG%20jQUVIiiXFxVyxBJVAqUCVMlkunyCACswElSdAlBXjedlTT5zDBUEE32RACFvuFrFeFQCVbYpfXhHCeDUGp6CxAI5DCKNzDEGgNAoMQjCqepfDDg1AAqmbVWV7ocFVUDSDVzgQC6DWVbd2XgLl%20WFcVpXlSSdAcMg-2Q4whDepEiBpOg4g8uEmyQIeSD1elq1TRt%20HAUhcUGCg2AGAYh2wvCL3nRIl3Xfyd3rY9z1nRdz6qA1ABCyJQAgxA3gAklABrENgKBIFAKCEDY2XEJ5KP7r9x42SjKtIBgmPQN04gSFABjhBVqNGggprAFrLmoy8FVVdLR7ZI4hAQAmZNQOLpXS9lTHHjjulQHFjiIMw3QYO6KtO6H0Bnd7%20uzgA-MJ4DQAAoiRxvbRgslQPN0mrJE3ZqPJpQsaLKmCwgGmS9punoFzogW0ZsgmWZFmqFZM4RFABcBvEi2ebZk0OTZshj9s8QyTurqBcAwX%20RlWXxoDkQON9-2PQa8S2qUYU8cX6Btek0WdfFiUpcLeqfWHvyK8rVvu0fR5O1rUs3rpPAcAfjQGcCnSW14oaQFPqHN4LVIo3w6rFJIu1659QGjAmBDUd5vyVirBwcAQAo1xvjGB58aYINvsgna3ViC9UfoNISwQbqmhdkXS8kCF7IAnjZZa45C7xCpltWmD8YTHVOq9CsN1eYPSeuzIWQQ2GCNfNTQiKC9oX1FizcR8jOZSJ5vdfmui3qKIEUgIRF9aY9W0WzQWeirrHgMXzORdiTEuiAA).

  - There are other lines with issues, such as `this.commandHandler.executeHandler("commandA", 5);` and `removeHandler` being incorrect (you can't use `.filter` to remove properties from `object` values), but that's another question.

Comment: Thank you, as written above the TS playground now shows me Error in line 45:

Argument of type '[number]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Parameters<H["commandA"]>'.(2345)

This error should be connected to the named typing, or?

Comment: @IngoFischer As I said above, that's a separate question entirely. Questions on StackOverflow should only be about 1 specific problem, or multiple _related_ problems - but your error about `Parameters<T>` is an unrelated separate problem, so post a new question for that.

Comment: Ok sorry I do not get that ... it works in other places while itwas the old and it also works in the extended class ... just not in the SimpleClass anymore ... 
Myunderstand is that it is that way because HandleObj is "not specifying" any allowed handler values.

Comment: For me it is related because in Fact "SimpleClass" has a defined "set" of commands that needs to be usable there. "command A" in the example case.
ExtendedClass adds "commandB" has another allowed value and here the goal is that both are useable. That's the point of my question how to achieve this.
The answer allows me to have "commandA and commandB" useable in the extended class, but now "commandA" is no longer working in the SimpleClass.